Cocos2d-x project crashes only on android 14 (SDK 34)
I'm working on a project developed with Cocos2d-x. Using org.cocos2dx.lib, I have successfully ported it to Android in Android Studio. However, I'm encountering a crash issue that only occurs on Android 14 (SDK 34). Crashes immediately upon launch on Android 14. The application runs fine on other versions of Android.
The app runs without issues on Android 13, but I encounter a crash on Android 14 (SDK 34). The error message in logcat is:
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: obj==null
in call to CallObjectMethodV
from void org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(int, int)
This error message only show in Android 14.
Are there known issues or specific changes required for compatibility with Android 14?
What steps can I take to debug or resolve this JNI error?

rebuild cocos2d with debug information and run in a debugger.  Clearly that method is calling some method on a null object.

The last version of cocos2d-x is from 5 years back. I have around 40 apps using cocos2d-x and i ran into several problems with the old version 4.0 in combination with new android version and iOS versions.
I am now using Axmol engine (fork of cocos2d-x 4.0) Axmol.org with almost no changes needed (cocos:: to ax::) (CCLOG to AXLOG) works perfect and bugs are fixed fast.
JNI in this project can help you.
But if you still want to use cocos2d-x:
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_axmol_lib_AxmolRenderer_nativeRender(JNIEnv*, jclass)
{
    ax::Director::getInstance()->mainLoop();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_axmol_lib_AxmolRenderer_nativeOnPause(JNIEnv*, jclass)
{
    if (Director::getInstance()->getGLView())
    {
        Application::getInstance()->applicationDidEnterBackground();
        ax::EventCustom backgroundEvent(EVENT_COME_TO_BACKGROUND);
        ax::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->dispatchEvent(&backgroundEvent);
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_axmol_lib_AxmolRenderer_nativeOnResume(JNIEnv*, jclass)
{
    static bool firstTime = true;
    if (Director::getInstance()->getGLView())
    {
        // don't invoke at first to keep the same logic as iOS
        // can refer to https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/14206
        if (!firstTime)
            Application::getInstance()->applicationWillEnterForeground();

        ax::EventCustom foregroundEvent(EVENT_COME_TO_FOREGROUND);
        ax::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->dispatchEvent(&foregroundEvent);

        firstTime = false;
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_axmol_lib_AxmolRenderer_nativeInsertText(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jstring text)
{
    std::string strValue = ax::StringUtils::getStringUTFCharsJNI(env, text);
    const char* pszText  = strValue.c_str();
    ax::IMEDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->dispatchInsertText(pszText, strlen(pszText));
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_axmol_lib_AxmolRenderer_nativeDeleteBackward(JNIEnv*, jclass)
{
    ax::IMEDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->dispatchDeleteBackward();
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_axmol_lib_AxmolRenderer_nativeGetContentText(JNIEnv* env, jclass)
{
    auto pszText = ax::IMEDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->getContentText();
    return ax::StringUtils::newStringUTFJNI(env, pszText);
}

